# Server handling client disconnects

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

Below this post, is my ChatApp's client disconnect handler, where it removed the disconnected client from the ListView, it perfectly but the CPU usage suddenly goes up to 50% when the client disconnects. How can I fix it?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!client.Client.Connected)
                        {
                            session.Stop();
                            session.tcpclient = null;
                            Clients.Remove(session);
                            listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                            {
                                ListViewItem data = new ListViewItem(session.listItems);
                                listView1.Items.RemoveAt((session.index));
                                listView1.Refresh();
                            }));

                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
            });
```

I tried putting it in a Thread but didn't work.

Comment: Not sure but it's a pretty bad idea to sleep threads in such a manner. Why not use task delay especially since you're using tasks anyway. Even worse you catch all exceptions. That's not something you want to do

Comment: Try to debug your code what is happening when its happening and implement some logging facility so you get some info out of your code about what is happening even if the concrete problem you are facing isn't easily debugable.

Comment: Why does it keep trying over and over again, instead of just going once?

Comment: Because if I don't, then it won't remove it from ListView, I tried it.

Comment: why is there a `while (true)` loop here *at all*? most likely, something is now throwing an exception (that you're swallowing) before the `Thread.Sleep`, so you now have a hot loop that runs forever: `while`, (exception), `catch`